# Modify SharePoint 2010 document library using Java

Tags: java, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In my SharePoint site, there are several document libraries, each assigned to a different group of people. Users need to transfer files between them often, and my boss wants a faster way than copy/pasting the files into another library then deleting the original, and he doesn't want anyone having direct access to the document hierarchy.

Someone had the idea to run Java code that would automatically transfer documents from one library to another, using inputs from a pop-up for the source and destination. Can Java code be stored on a SharePoint server and be executed by a user action?

Answer (score 0):

Java code can not be used SharePoint directly. What you can try is using C# or VB.Net through which actions can be executed on SharePoint using object model of SharePoint.

Another option is using web services

1、You can use then Copy.asmx web service to upload document:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy(v=office.12).aspx

2、upload large file:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Answer (score 0):

3、About authenication:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy.copyintoitems(v=office.12)

4、You can use these web services from java:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/478814/Web-Services/java/Microsoft-Sharepoint-web-service-Java
[SharePoint Webservice from Java Webapp using CXF with Kerberos/NTLM authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361840/sharepoint-webservice-from-java-webapp-using-cxf-with-kerberos-ntlm-authenticati)
[Authentication failure calling SharePoint Web Service (JAX-WS client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414622/authentication-failure-calling-sharepoint-web-service-jax-ws-client)

Regards
Hiren Gondhiya

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a WCF service in SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521584(v=office.14).aspx) and then consume it from your Java application.